# how to delete all the numbers that follow it and keep only the last

Tags: php, regex

I would like to delete all the numbers that follow except the last.

Example:

```
test test 1 1 1 255 255 test 7.log
```

I want to transform by:

```
test test test 255 7.log
```

I tried numerous combinations, but the best I found with this result is wrong:

```
test test 55 test 7.log
```

I thank everyone for their invaluable assistance, this site is great.

Comment: Do some google before ask

Comment: Please post exactly what code you tried. We can't help you if we only see the results of your attempts.

Comment: If you say why you are trying to do this there may even be a better way.

Comment: In your example that you want to transform you have not only removed all numbers but also swapped place on the last "test" and "255". Is this intentional?

Answer (score 0):

if you need to remove all numbers except the last:

```
$file = "test test 1 1 1 255 255 test 7.log";
list($name, $ext) = explode('.', $file);
// split the file into chunks
$chunks = explode(' ', $name);
$new_chunks = array();
// find all numeric positions
foreach($chunks as $k => $v) {
    if(is_numeric($v)) 
        $new_chunks[] = $k;
}
// remove the last position
array_pop($new_chunks);
// for any numeric position delete if from our list
foreach($new_chunks as $k => $v) {
        unset($chunks[$v]);
}
// merge the chunks again.
$file = implode(' ', $chunks) . '.' .$ext;
var_dump($file);
```

Output:

```
string(20) "test test test 7.log"
```

---

If you want to remove all the dublicate numbers then:

```
$file = "test test 1 1 1 255 255 test 7.log";
list($name, $ext) = explode('.', $file);
$chunks = explode(' ', $name);
$new_chunks = array();
$output = array();
foreach($chunks as $k => $v) {
    if(is_numeric($v)){
        if(!in_array($v, $new_chunks)) {
        $output[] = $v;
        $new_chunks[] = $v;
    }} else 
        $output[] = $v;
}
var_dump(implode(' ', $output). '.' .$ext);
```

Output:

```
string(26) "test test 1 255 test 7.log"
```